# Errors in using nls function in R

Tags: r, excel

I have been trying to use the nls function in R on a temperature model. I have to estimate 2 parameters called s0 and Tch.

I have imported a set of data from Excel, in which I have 4 columns of 9998 rows : Date, Treelle, Tretrelevee, and Tcons. I am trying to understand how a heating controller in a building. I want to calculate the temperature (Tdep) tanks to a temperature setpoint (Tcons) and the return tempeature (Tretrelevee) and compare it with the measured temperature (Tdepreelle).

Here is a sample of my data :

```
   donneesbis <- structure(list(Tcons = c(51.6099999999998, 53.1362499999993, 
                                   45.4742499999993, 44.0543749999995, 57.8999999999997, 49.7168333333327, 
                                   45.7269999999998, 46.0214583333331, 53.1855833333333, 46.9418333333326, 
                                   52.2359166666666, 45.3108333333328, 44.2624999999995, 44.1653749999997, 
                                   47.3951666666659), Tret.relevee = c(43.764166666666, 44.8750000000001, 
                                                                       37.9016666666671, 36.2000000000002, 46.5000000000003, 41.514999999999, 
                                                                       39.9133333333328, 39.6116666666664, 40.2916666666656, 41.8299999999993, 
                                                                       41.1224999999992, 36.5, 36.3250000000002, 43.8758333333327, 38.2700000000001
                                   ), Treelle.30sec = c(47.4999999999989, 48.6250000000003, 40.7016666666667, 
                                                        38.6125000000001, 50.5999999999987, 44.7766666666672, 42.6600000000008, 
                                                        42.5116666666667, 43.7849999999998, 44.6649999999998, 44.1483333333336, 
                                                        38.8999999999999, 38.7250000000001, 47.9008333333323, 41.1833333333334
                                   )), .Names = c("Tcons", "Tret.relevee", "Treelle.30sec"), row.names = c(8478L, 
                                                                                                           7231L, 6122L, 3466L, 9721L, 5064L, 1857L, 2348L, 1052L, 4575L, 
                                                                                                           1352L, 3653L, 3496L, 8654L, 6429L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here are my functions. They are recursive, which makes it more complicated :

Tdep(t) = sigma(t-1) (Tch - Tretrelevee(t)) + Tretrelevee(t)

where sigma(t) = ((100-2*s0)/32)*1.25*(Tcons(t)-Tdep(t)) + s0.

In addition, sigma should not be 100-s0.

It is clearer written like this, but in the code I only wrote one function :
Tdep(t) = (((100-2*s0)/32)*1.25*(Tcons(t-1)-Tdep(t-1)) + s0)*(Tch - Tretrelevee(t)) + Tretrelevee(t)

The parameters I want to estimate are s0 and Tch.

Here is the code :

```
Tdep <-  function(s0,Tch,tps) {
   if (tps == 1)     {return (37.9)}
   else if ((((100-2*s0)/32)*1.25*(donneesbis$Tcons[tps-1]-Tdep(s0,Tch,tps-1))+s0) <= s0) {return ((s0/100)*(Tch - donneesbis$Tret.relevee[tps])+donneesbis$Tret.relevee[tps])}
   else if ((((100-2*s0)/32)*1.25*(donneesbis$Tcons[tps-1]-Tdep(s0,Tch,tps-1))+s0) >= 100 - s0) {return (((100-s0)/100)*(Tch - donneesbis$Tret.relevee[tps])+donneesbis$Tret.relevee[tps])}
   else {return (((((100-2*s0)/32)*1.25*(donneesbis$Tcons[tps-1]-Tdep(s0,Tch,tps-1))+s0)/100)*(Tch - donneesbis$Tret.relevee[tps])+donneesbis$Tret.relevee[tps])}}
```

With this formula, I can calculate each value one by one, but I cannot calculate a serie of values :

```
> x <- 1:10
> Tdep(15,60,x)
[1] 37.9
Warning message:
In if (tps == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Though I have :

```
> Tdep(15,60,15)

[1] 41.5295
```

Therefore when I use nls :

```
x <- 1:15 
nls(donneesbis$Treelle.30sec~ Tdepbis(s0,Tch0,x), data = donneesbis, start = list(s1=15,Tch1=60))
```

I get this error in return :

```
Error in qr(.swts * attr(rhs, "gradient")) : 
  dims [product 2] do not match the length of object [9998]
```

And this warning message :

```
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (tps == 1) { :
```

Thanks to research on this website, I also tried with the "ifelse" function :

```
Tdepbis <-  function(s0,Tch,tps) {
  ifelse(tps <= 1,37.9,{if ((((100-2*s0)/32)*1.25*(donneesbis$Tcons[tps-1]-    Tdepbis(s0,Tch,tps-1))+s0) <= s0) {return ((s0/100)*(Tch - donneesbis$Tret.relevÃ.e[tps])+donneesbis$Tret.relevÃ.e[tps])}
  else if ((((100-2*s0)/32)*1.25*(donneesbis$Tcons[tps-1]-Tdepbis(s0,Tch,tps-1))+s0) >= 100 - s0) {return (((100-s0)/100)*(Tch - donneesbis$Tret.relevÃ.e[tps])+donneesbis$Tret.relevÃ.e[tps])}
  else {return (((((100-2*s0)/32)*1.25*(donneesbis$Tcons[tps-1]-Tdepbis(s0,Tch,tps-1))+s0)/100)*(Tch - donneesbis$Tret.relevÃ.e[tps])+donneesbis$Tret.relevÃ.e[tps])}
  })
}
```

And, using nls the same way as before, I get this error message :

```
Error in donneesbis$Tcons[tps - 1] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

I have trouble understanding what the first error is, since I have checked that Treelle and Tdep had the same length, and I can't solve the second error.

I could not fine any solution that couls solve my problem on forum or in R help.

Would someone have any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please provide some example data and describe your temperature model. It's probably easier to solve this from scratch than guessing what you want to achieve based on your code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i have added a sample of my data and a bit of explanation. I am completely new both to that forum and to R, I hope it will work

Comment: Try to write a simple example and as Roland said describe your model. It's not possible to run your code.

Comment: Please provide the mathematical formulas for your function. It looks like it is recursive (which is a challenge).

Comment: i added the formulas and an example. Indeed, the function is recursive, which makes the code complicated and quite unclear ... And this is the source of most of the errors I have !

Answer (score 1):

You need an efficient function. Thus, I would implement it in Rcpp (check if the formulas are correct):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector temps(const NumericVector Tcons,
                    const NumericVector Tretrelevee,
                    const double s0,
                    const double Tch,
                    const double Tdep0) {
  int n = Tcons.size();
  NumericVector res(n);
  double sigma;
  res(0) = Tdep0;
  for (int t = 1; t < n; t++) {
    sigma = (((100-2*s0)/32)*1.25*(Tcons(t-1)-res(t-1)) + s0);
    if (sigma < s0) sigma = s0;
    if (sigma > (100 - s0)) sigma = (100 - s0);
    res(t) = sigma * (Tch - Tretrelevee(t)) + Tretrelevee(t);
  }

  return res;
}
```

(Follow [these instructions](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486088-Using-Rcpp-with-RStudio) if you have never used it. Briefly, you need to install Rtools if you use Windows and then open a C++ file in RStudio. Copy this code into it and source it.)

Then you can do this in R:

```
fit <- nls(Treelle.30sec ~ temps(Tcons, Tret.relevee, s0, Tch, 37.9), 
      data = donneesbis, start = list(s0 = 1, Tch = 1))
summary(fit)  
#Formula: Treelle.30sec ~ temps(Tcons, Tret.relevee, s0, Tch, 37.9)
#
#Parameters:
#    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#s0  100.1629     0.2307 434.093   <2e-16 ***
#Tch  21.4532    27.1098   0.791    0.443    
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 2.673 on 13 degrees of freedom
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 4 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.533e-08

plot(donneesbis$Treelle.30sec)
lines(predict(fit), col = "red")
```

[image: resulting plot]

No idea why you chose 37.9 as the starting temperature. 47.5 seems like the obvious choice.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helps a lot and it now seems to be working. I just have another question :
I have to use the algorithm port because I have to put constraints on my parameters : 
fit <- nls(Treelle30sec ~ temps(Tcons, Tretrelevee, s0, Tch, 37.9), 
           data = donneesbis, start = list(s0 = 15, Tch = 80), algorithm = "port", lower = c(1,50), upper = c(30,95),control = nls.control(maxiter = 1000, minFactor = 1/1024),trace = T)

But I do not understand what the last line of my result means :
Algorithm "port", convergence message: relative convergence (4)